# python eel is not working when run as root

Tags: python, scapy, eel

I am working on a project with eel and scapy. for scapy sniff, root access is required. I've created virtual environment. scapy part runs fine with root. eel part runs fine without root. but when I tried running eel part with root, nothing is displayed.
on terminating and running again, it gives following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use: ('localhost', 8000)
```

It is creating a zombie process.
to run I first switched to root, then activated virtual environment and then run eel.py
Even when port is changed, same thing happens.

f any of you could help me, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Something is already bound on that port. On modern Linuxes, you can use `ss -ltpn` to find out what process that is.

Comment: yes, the same eel/chrome is using that port. it is not being closed properly and being turned into zombie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by elevating privileges of python by using setcap so I won't have to use sudo to run scapy

to elevate privileges I used

```
setcap cap_net_raw=eip /usr/bin/python3.8
```

to revoke the privileges I used

```
setcap -r /usr/bin/python3.8
```